# C++ include header not working

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I am learning some basic concepts of C++ and I am stuck in using multiple files using headers. 
I have 3 files.

Calculator.h

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H_CAL
#define CALCULATOR_H_CAL
class Calculator{
        int a,b;
        public:
        Calculator();
        Calculator(int,int);
    int op();
};
#endif
```

Calculator.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Calculator.h"

    Calculator::Calculator(){
        a=0;b=0;
    }
    Calculator::Calculator(int c,int d){
        a=c;b=d;    
    }
    int Calculator::op(){
        return a*b;
    }
```

Main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Calculator.h"    

int main(){
    Calculator a(2,3);
    int b=a.op();
    std::cout << b;
}
```

But compiling with g++ Main.cpp gives errors:

```
/tmp/cc09isjx.o: In function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `Calculator::Calculator(int, int)'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `Calculator::op()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: because he can't find the implementation of the methods. try g++ Main.cpp Calculator.cpp

Comment: Header inclusion is a compilation matter, you have no problem with that. Undefined reference is a linking matter, totally unrelated to headers.

Comment: Ohh. I dint know, you need to specify all the file names. Thanks.

Comment: you need to specify the files for the linking part

Comment: Since you're just beginning to learn C++, some things you should learn right now are the notions of "compilation unit" and "linking". There is extensive documentation on that matter so I'll let you research it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you compiling the code? I believe the issue is that you aren't linking the calculator files with the main when compiling. Try this:

```
g++ -c calculator.cpp
g++ main.cpp -o main calculator.o
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not linking the the files with main() correctly, then you won't be able to compile it correctly.

try this-

g++ main.cpp Calculator.cpp

This should now include your header file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command to comlile:

```
g++ Main.cpp Calculator.cpp
```